# AppInsight on-prem VM CPU/MEM no data

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

i've an issue with Application Insight, in particular with CPU/MEM on-prem server monitor (other telemetries data are OK).
I've this error:

> Error collecting 11 of the configured performance counters. Please
>   check the configuration.  Counter \Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\%
>   Processor Time: Failed to perform the first read for performance
>   counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: Process, counter: %
>   Processor Time, instance   Counter \Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\%
>   Processor Time Normalized: Failed to perf....

but my application.config configuration in only this

```
<Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="Processor Time" />
</Counters>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Additional information:
the application pool user is into Performance Monitor Users group and the Performance Log Users group

Comment: Where is the webapp hosted?

Comment: Hi @cijothomas, on prem WIN16 + IIS

Comment: mm..Are you able to observe the values for perf counters using tools like PerfMon ? (Also post the full error message if possible) If the counter are corrupted - try this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2554336/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counters-for-windows-server-2008-6